# Sticky Footer Not Working when Header is Fixed and Main has Top Margin?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

Please paste the `HTML` below into your browser (using your browser's console - preferably Chrome) to see the problem I'm having.

**Prerequisites :**

- A fixed header at the top
- A main container of variable height with a top margin
- A footer that sticks to the bottom of the page. Not a fixed footer but a sticky
  one.

**Problem :** The height of `.main` will vary depending on its content. At certain window widths (always depending on the variable height of `.main`) there is a gap left between the `.footer` and the bottom of the window.

**Goal :** I want to get rid of the gap underneath `.footer` and I want `.footer` to stick to the bottom. I want it to **stick**, *I don't want it to be fixed*.

If you're confused simply paste the below in your browser and play around with the window width to see what I'm talking about. :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
        z-index: 99999;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
      .main {
        position: relative;
        border: 5px solid rgb(0, 255, 42);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 1.3;
        color: white;
        padding: 45px;
        background-color: green;
        top: 100px;
      }
      .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
        border: 5px solid blue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top: 100px;
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="main">gaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd fgfyh rtyf tr srtgb srfhgaberrfgherbg rthf strhd</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest using the [sticky-footer-approach](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) and add a fixed navbar:

http://jsfiddle.net/L8m54b5t/1/

html

```
<div class="page-wrap">

    Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
    I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: #eee;
}

.page-wrap {
        padding-top: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -142px; 
        box-sizing:border-box;
}
.page-wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
    height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: If you look at your JSfiddle you'll see that it doesn't work. The 812px limit anyway is for when testing on the browser not on JSFiddle. I'll remove my JSFiddile to prevent further confusion. Apologies if it wasn't clear. More importantly, the 812px is just an example, and is related to the amount of text using in thsi specific case. I'm obviously looking for a solution that will work for any amount of text. Basically a solution that work for any height of `.main`.

Comment: Your solution has nothing to do with the problem I am having. You have changed the HTML I provided. I have a fixed header and a main with a top margin and a variable height. Your solution has ignored all of the above.

Comment: I had a look at your jsfiddle and it's not working. There is a gap between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the window.

Comment: oh sorry. i fixed it.

Comment: well my friend. looks like you did it! :-) Bravo!